# Increment binary value in pic assembly every time button is pressed

Tags: assembly, pic

Trying to increment a value that is outputted to LED's by one each time a button has been pressed. The code i have written so far is as follows:

```
    LIST P=16F84A
    INCLUDE <P16F84A.INC>

    ; Set configuration bits
    __CONFIG _CP_OFF & _WDT_OFF & _PWRTE_ON & _XT_OSC

; Main Program ------------------------------------------------------------
code1    EQU    0x2
Start
                bsf STATUS, RP0         ;Go to bank 1
                movlw b'11111111'       ;
                movwf TRISA             ;Set the port pin types of the RA

                movlw b'00000000'       ;
                movwf TRISB             ;Set the port pin types of the RB
                bcf STATUS, RP0         ;Go to bank 0
MainLoop
                btfss PORTA,4
                goto Button_Is_Off

Button_Is_On
                movlw d'0'              ; binary value to output on PORTB
                movwf PORTB             ; output the binary value on PORTB
                goto MainLoop

Button_Is_Off
                movlw code1+1           ; binary value to output on PORTB
                movwf PORTB             ; output the binary value on PORTB
                goto MainLoop
      
    end                                 ; end of program
```

How would i modify this (I believe the line `movlw code1+1`) to properly increment the value? At the moment the value is increased by 1 once, not each time the button is pressed.

Thanks

Comment: When you can explain the difference between loading the W register with an immediate value and a value stored in a file register comback and edit the code you posted.

Comment: We were all beginners once, I'm just trying to learn @Dan1138

Comment: Looks like you've deleted your previous question. You should consider adding a delay routine to debounce the button input since the buttons are mechanical and can emit some noise between the mechanical pressed state changes. ~50 to 100ms of delay would be enough to filter that noisy digital signal which the MCU would interpret it as a state change since it works quite fast in a second.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In assembly language each operation is specified using an instruction of the related architecture's instruction set which in your case is an 8-bit PIC architecture.
So an operation like `a = a+1;` or `a++;` in C lang, can be done using just one instruction: `incf a, F` in assembly lang, thanks to the synchronous up/down counter nature of the underlying registers. With this instruction, the CPU reads the actual value of `a`, then it increments the value (count up), and finally it writes the updated value to `a` since we've used the `F` flag or bit, which tells the CPU to save the updated value to the variable itself (By the way, the variable is an allocated location in the general purpose registers (GPR) of built-in RAM). If we would have put the `W` flag instead of `F`, the CPU would save the updated value in the W (Working) register.

But if you increment a variable using a value other than 1 as in `a = a + 5` for example, then instructions would change in assembly lang since there is no one specific instruction to do this simple math operation as in the previous example. The operation would be the following in assembly:

```
movlw   5
addwf   a, F
```

In this piece of code, the following steps will be taken by the CPU:

- The literal value 5 will be loaded from program memory to the W register
- Then the CPU will add this value to `a`
- The result of the operation will be saved into the `a` variable

After this brief introduction of how values are incremented in PIC assembly, you must understand how important it is to get familiar with what each instruction does in order to be able to write code in assembly. Now let's get back to your existing code and update it according to the desired operation you want it to perform.
As far as I understand, you want it to count-up one by one on every hit and release of the button. But waiting for the button release to update the output would be a bit annoying. That's why we ideally update the output as soon as we detect the button press and then wait for another press. To do this however, requires the knowledge of button release as well. To do this we need to scan the button in each loop to determine the button state and then update the output accordingly. As you can see we are breaking down the problem into smaller problems to deal with each one by one or step by step. Doing so, makes it easier to write code for each small problem instead of trying to resolve all at once.

The problems that we have:

- Scanning a button properly without false triggering
- Updating the output according to the state of the button

We can even break them down further if needed. For example, the scanning of a button needs to be done in a few steps. So let's specify the steps using a pseudo algorithm:

- Scanning a button properly without false triggering

  1. Read the actual input state
  2. Filter out the input noise by using a small delay*
  3. Confirm that the input state is stable
  4. Proceed for the new input state

Now that we designed a pseudo program flow, we can implement it in code:

```
    LIST P=16F84A
    INCLUDE <P16F84A.INC>

    ; Set configuration bits
    __CONFIG _CP_OFF & _WDT_OFF & _PWRTE_ON & _XT_OSC

; Main Program ------------------------------------------------------------
Start:
    bsf STATUS, RP0         ;Go to bank 1
    movlw b'11111111'       ;
    movwf TRISA             ;Set the port pin types of the RA

    movlw b'00000000'       ;
    movwf TRISB             ;Set the port pin types of the RB
    bcf STATUS, RP0         ;Go to bank 0

MainLoop:
    ; Wait for a button press
    btfss   PORTA, 4    ; Read the actual input state
    goto    MainLoop
    ; A button press is detected
    call    delay_50ms  ; TODO filter the noise out
    btfss   PORTA, 4    ; confirm that the press is stable
    goto    MainLoop    ; wait for a stable press
    ; button press is stable, proceed
    
    ; update the output
    incf    PORTB, F    ; increment the value of port B
    
    ; Now wait for button to be released
waitForButtonRelease:
    btfsc   PORTA, 4
    goto    waitForButtonRelease
    call    delay_50ms  ; TODO filter the noise out
    btfsc   PORTA, 4    ; confirm the release is stable
    goto    waitForButtonRelease
    ; button release is stable, loop back to the main and wait for
    ; a new button press
    goto    MainLoop
    
delay_50ms:
    ; TODO you are encouraged to implement this 50ms delay
    return
    
    END
```

---

I encourage you to implement this delay routine for 50 ms. That's why I will leave it empty. It will be functional but will return immediately without any delay (It will actually produce ~4 instruction cycles of delay in reality, but this is not enough time to filter out an input noise). You can google as *pic assembly delay* or search it in Stackoverflow using this google search: *pic assembly delay site:stackoverflow.com*. You will see that there is plenty of information on that.
Try to understand the program flow and logic, simulate it step by step in MPLABX simulator to understand things better. Finally let me know if something is unclear for you.